# Visual Studio 2017 unable to load project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to load my VS2015 project into the newly installed VS2017RC but it keeps giving me the error (when loading or reloading):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It also tells me:

> "The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information",

but reload throws me the NullRef exception.

**How do I know what is wrong with my VS Instance, where can I find info about the error?**

I tried the Event Viewer but that has not been very resourceful.

[image: Project Image]

[image: Solution Output]

**UPDATE**
Event viewer info
[image: Event log 1, App crash]
[image: Event log 2, Stacktrace]

Comment: Have you installed WCF? It's an optional component. Perhaps VS is downloading the feature, or simply crashed because WCF is missing

Comment: Nope, I have WCF. But how do I get more info/details about what is going wrong?

Comment: A "Refresh" release came out [yesterday](https://www.visualstudio.com/nb-no/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes). You should update through the Visual Studio Installer and try again. You can check the [Fixed Issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/fixed-in%3A+Visual+Studio+2017+RC.html), perhaps there is a similar issue there

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes, but not any useful info... WIll update this post with Event viewer info

Comment: [Similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3200/project-load-failed-error-object-reference-not-set.html). The line `<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />` was causing problems. You should *still* update though, as the RC Refresh has a simplified `csproj` schema. The offending line could be dropped when migrating to the new schema

Comment: @Panagiotis Excellent, this is the solution, however the question is how to get that info, how would I resolve future VS errors? Please post answer and I will accept it

Comment: As Simon Colmer writes on that issue, trial and error. Which could mean commenting out sections of `csproj` until the project starts working again. *Maybe* you could increase the logging level of MSBuild to "Diagnostic" from "Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run". I'm not sure if that affects loading projects though

Comment: Have you tried looking into the VS activity log? You can start devenv with `/log` parameter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Possible cause #1:**

Try adding this to your project file, or check if it has that or not:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion> 
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Possible cause #2:

Removing the two import lines that contain:

```
 "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
```

Hope one of these works. The first one worked for me.

Comment: Anyone know what is the effect of removing that lines?

Comment: Seconding @nacho1493. Even though this is a very common strategy here on SO, randomly deleting stuff "just cause" is not a very sustainable solution. It would be nice to know what we are deleting here and how it affects the overall system / stability.